# Export model without materials?

Tags: materials, export

Any way to do it? Or maybe turn materials "off" temporary? The problem I am trying to solve is this: I make a model with different materials only to create a material ID map. If I export it as FBX to Substance Painter, it has several "texture sets" (equal to the number of materials) once loaded in the latter app. That adds an extra step to the workflow: merging maps after export. If I could "turn off" materials before exporting from blender it wold be much easier.

Mind: I obviously can just delete materials before exporting, but I fear that when iterating on some changes I might forget to revert the deleted materials and loose all my data.

Comment: In the export options, try exporting as mesh only

Comment: DId not find those options for the fbx, what kind of file format do you suggest?

Comment: If you try to export, in blender there is a row of options highlighted on the bottom left. Try with only mesh selected over there.

Comment: I already did - it still exports the materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if exporting as Wavefront's .obj file there is a check box "Write materials", unchecking which solves the problem. .obj is widely used and will work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your model:
[image]

Export it as `Collada(default)(.dae)`:
[image]

Then import your Collada (`.dae`) file and export it as `.fbx`:
[image]

Results:
You will have an fbx without textures

Hope this helps

NOTE: I am not the creator of the 3D model in the images.

Comment: Well, I already posted an answer that works and requires less steps. Btw, my experiments with .dae showed that it preserves material information. Maybe when you re-import it. But still it's just too much stuff to do.